# Save geotagged images to new directory using exiftool

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to use exiftool in command line.

By default exiftool saves geotagged image in the same directory where the original image is. Can I change this behavior and change the directory of geotagged image to new directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the [`-o` option](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#o-OUTFILE-or-FMT--out).  The second example under [Writing Examples](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#WRITING-EXAMPLES) shows this option.  In your case, it would be something like:
`exiftool -GPSLatitude=0.000 -GPSLongitude=0.000 -GPSLatitudeRef=S -GPSLongitudeRef=W -o /path/to/New/GPSTaggedFiles/ /Source/Path/`